# Starting an activity after google maps is closed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, onsaveinstancestate

In my Application when a Button is clicked it redirects the user to Google Maps App on the mobile using the following code

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + a + "," + b);
                                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                                    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                                    startActivity(mapIntent);
```

now What I want is to when the user closes the Google Maps/ returns to My app, it should start a different activity rather than the one it was left on.
Is it possible to do this? I've used a delay to start the secondary activity but it's not giving the result I need as sometimes it runs over the Google Maps app.
Im fairly new to Android studio altogether.

Edit- is onSaveInstanceState is a possible way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be couple approaches to solve that issue. For example by using `static Map<K,O>` and monitoring `Activity` lifecycle. But because `static` member should be handled properly to avoid leaking why not use `SharedPreferences`.

For example in above part of code where you start `Google Maps` you can save status in `SharedPreferences` just call:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("maps", true)
            .apply();
```

And when `Google Maps` are launched your app will go in `onPause` state so after user closes the `Google Maps` your app will be `resumed` so `onResume` method will be called there you can check status:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean isComingFromMaps = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getBoolean("maps", false);
if(isComingFromMaps) {
  //Launch your activity here

  //also don't forget to save value back to false to avoid bug when next time Activity is started 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("maps", false)
            .apply();
    }
}
```

Also last checking is to make sure if user doesn't return from maps rather he minimises both apps, or kill them you want to set value back to `false` before `super.onDestroy()` is called. Like:

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("maps", false)
            .apply();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) there is a method: `startActivities(Intent[] intents, Bundle options)`

I personally have never used it before, but seems to be what you want.
Here is the code. I tried it and it worked. It is in Kotlin, but you can re-write it in Java. Note: Make sure you start the map activity as the second in the array.

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=$a,$b")
        val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
        val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        val intents = arrayOf(i, mapIntent)
        startActivities(intents, null)
```